# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^2}{n^4+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

> Evaluate
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^2}{n^4+1}$$

Does anyone have any smart ideas how to evaluate such a sum? I know one solution with complex numbers and complex analysis but I'm looking for some more smart or sophisticated methods.

Comment: If you are looking for a real analysis solution, then why are the tags complex-analysis and complex-numbers appropriate?

Comment: not necessarily for a real analysis! I haven’t said that. But maybe there is a nice solution in complex analysis but not that I already know

Comment: Well, what one do you already know?

Comment: Let $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(n^4+1) \sin( \pi z)}$. We found poles, residuums of $f(z)$ and use Cauchy's residue formula

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry, it should be $z^4+1$, not $n^4+1$

Comment: What contour did you use?

Comment: $\Gamma_N$ which is a square with vertices $\pm (N+\frac{1}{2} ) \pm (N+\frac{1}{2})i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say that it is elegant, but:

The form $n^4+1$ in the denominator suggests that one should be able to get this series by expanding a combination of a hyperbolic and trigonometric function in a Fourier series.

Indeed, after some trial and error, the following function seems to work:

$$
\begin{gathered}
\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\sin
   \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\cos \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
+ \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cosh
   \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\sin \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \sinh
   \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{gathered}
$$

It is even, and its cosine coefficients are
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}\bigl(\cos(\sqrt{2}\pi)-\cosh(\sqrt{2}\pi)\bigr)(-1)^{n+1} n^2}{\pi(1+n^4)},\quad n\geq 1.
$$
(The zero:th coefficient is also zero). Evaluating at $x=0$ (the series converges pointwise there) gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^2}{1+n^4}=
\frac{\pi\left(\sin
   \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) \sinh \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{2}\bigl(\cosh(\sqrt{2}\pi)-\cos(\sqrt{2}\pi)\bigr)}\approx 0.336.
$$

Comment: That seems like quite a bit of trial and error and a bit contrived in a way.  But if does give the correct result so (+1)

Comment: @MarkViola Well, it was not so difficult, just make the correct ansatz and find the appropriate constants. But I agree it is not really elegant, smart or sophisticated. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @mickep Could you please give more explanations and steps of this? It seems interesting but I cannot undestand any single step etc

Comment: Honestly, when you say that you don't understand a single step I have no clue where to start.

Comment: @mickep Maybe you could give me some links where I could see details or algorithms of such combination of a hyperbolic and trigonometric function

Comment: If you just want formulas you could for example look in _Table of integrals, series, and products_ by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. If you want to understand the theory of Fourier series, then I recommend the book _Fourier analysis and its applications_ by Folland.

Answer (score -1):

Partial elements methods  should works but are boring.

Let's try smthg else : having $n^4$ and $n$ of the same parity

$$ (-1)^{n^4}=(-1)^n  $$ so
$$ u_n= \int_0^1 n^2(-t)^{n^4} $$

So you can begin to have fun with it (I'm searching as I'm writting )